# Can the Rpi 3 handle 4 cameras at the same time?

Tags: camera, processor-speed

I want to take 4 pictures simultaneously with 4 different cameras on the Raspberry Pi. I have found  [this multicamera adapter](http://www.uctronics.com/multi-camera-adapter-bundle-kits-compatible-for-official-raspberry-pi-v2-1pc-multiple-adapter-and-4-modified-v2-camera-module.html), but I do not know whether the Rpi can handle taking 4 pictures at the very same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not with this multicamera adapter, and not at all.

That adapter is a multiplexer. So at any given time you can pick on of four cameras and take a picture. You can switch to the next camera afterwards and take a picture and then switch to the next... you get the point. I am not sure about the speed but if all cameras stay online, it should not take too long. Like grabbing 1 garbage frame and then a complete frame. If the cameras don't stay online, then it will take approximately 5 frames to adjust brightnes and such each time you switch.

You might want to consider USB Webcams for that. Those are actually more expensive and offer a lower resolution if you try to come somewhere near the official RPi Cam, but definitively can run simultaneously. I had a setup of 3 very cheap 640x480 webcams running well.

Comment: I agree with this answer but what he is saying could be stated differently.  It can be done and you could keep the last frame up on the screen so you could have 4 images up at any given time but you would have a REALLY slow frame rate and they technically would not be streams.  You could conceivably create a screen that gives the appearance of 4 simultaneous images but they would not be.  the product description also has a disclaimer which basically says it may not work... buyer beware.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really the answer you are looking for but the Compute Modules do have native **dual** RPi camera support.  However one of the connectors has a full four data channel path and the other only two, but I guess the RPi cameras only use a pair {that does lead to a little bit of speculation as to whether that four channel one could be split so that two cameras could be run on that port for a total of three cameras overall, but I do not have any evidence to support that.}

The Foundation site has this page ["Attaching a Raspberry Pi Camera Module to the Compute Module IO Board"](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/cmio-camera.md), which might give further insight...